# Android studio run Gcmsender

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-messaging

I download a project demo from https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services and import the gcm project. there is a java modules named `gcmsender, after run GcmSender.main, logged`:

```
usage: ./gradlew run -Pargs="MESSAGE[,DEVICE_TOKEN]"
```

...

Example (Broadcast):

```
On Windows:   .\gradlew.bat run -Pargs="<Your_Message>"
On Linux/Mac: ./gradlew run -Pargs="<Your_Message>"
```

Example (Unicast):

```
On Windows:   .\gradlew.bat run -Pargs="<Your_Message>,<Your_Token>"
On Linux/Mac: ./gradlew run -Pargs="<Your_Message>,<Your_Token>"
```

nothing happened , why ?

Comment: It threw an error because it was expecting some arguments. The usage is as printed out by the errors: `./gradlew run -Pargs=...`

Run the terminal on your computer or go to the "Terminal" tab on Android Studio (View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal) and run that command.

Take note, this simulates what your GCM app server would do to send messages to your devices. Make sure you add in your API key and that you also understand what the app module does.